# Issue importing properties in test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, springrunner

In a `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` test, I want to import some properties defined in `com/.../test/resources/application.yml` but they are not well formatted. This issue does not replicate when running the application.

Configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my.property")
@Component
@Data
public class MyConfig{

    private List<String> val1;
    private List<String> val2;
}
```

main/.../application.yml:

```
my.property.val1: [string1, string2, string3]
my.property.val2: [string1, string2]
```

test/.../application.yml (just the same content):

```
my.property.val1: [string1, string2, string3]
my.property.val2: [string1, string2]
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyConfig myConfig;
```

When running the application, the object looks good (meaning that `val1` is a list of `string1`, `string2`, `string3`), but when running the unit test, the `[` and `]` are also included. For example, `val1` would be a list of the following Strings: `[string1`, `string2`, `string3]`

Basically, the issue is that the `[` and `]` characters are included (but this happens only on the testing part). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the test values as the following. Normal structure for array in yaml:

```
my.property.val1:
  - string1
  - string2
  - string3
my.property.val2:
  - string1
  - string2
```